# How to alter the results we get from the youtube-search-python package?

Tags: python, pip, youtube

I am using the youtube-search-python 1.3.1 module to search for the details about specific youtube videos.

Here is a link to its PyPi page: https://pypi.org/project/youtube-search-python/

My Code:

```
from youtubesearchpython import SearchVideos
search = SearchVideos("Video", offset = 1, mode = "json", max_results = 1)
print(search.result())
```

However, on doing so, it prints all the details(attributes) of the video as shown below:

```
{
    "search_result": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "id": "-_4GW6BNIqs",
            "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_4GW6BNIqs",
            "title": "Insideeus - Ecstasy (Official Video)",
            "channel": "InsideeusVEVO",
            "duration": "3:27",
            "views": 299442272,
            "thumbnails": [
                "https://img.youtube.com/vi/-_4GW6BNIqs/default.jpg",
                "https://img.youtube.com/vi/-_4GW6BNIqs/hqdefault.jpg",
                "https://img.youtube.com/vi/-_4GW6BNIqs/mqdefault.jpg",
                "https://img.youtube.com/vi/-_4GW6BNIqs/sddefault.jpg",
                "https://img.youtube.com/vi/-_4GW6BNIqs/maxresdefault.jpg"
            ],
            "channelId": "UCRNE_wppvoMBdj7EAtUnEog"
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to get the "link" part of this result to be printed. I am not able to get this even after many tries.

Does anyone know how to alter the code in order to print only the "link"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer.

```
import json
from youtubesearchpython import SearchVideos

search = SearchVideos("Video", offset = 1, mode = "json", max_results = 1)
r = search.result()
res = json.loads(r)
res1 = res['search_result']
res2 = res1[0]
res_fin = res2['link']
print(res_fin)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want more adavanced features, you can use searchtube. It provides you with filter options also.

```
pip install searchtube
```

Documentation can be found here : https://github.com/shekharchander/searchtube

Answer (score 0):

That's a dictionary and you access values by, e.g.,

```py
r = search.result()
for d in r['search_result']:
    print(d['link'])
```

Comment: I tried that out, but I am getting the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    for d in r['search_result']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: [Demo](https://repl.it/@JustinEzequiel/EachVainControlpanel) with a copy-paste of your dictionary